# Recurrence equation approximation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I have the following recurrence relation, $$x_{i+1}=a\cdot x_i^{\frac{2-2\alpha}{3}}+x_i,$$ 
where $a>0, \alpha>0$, and $x_0>0$.
My goal is to get an approximate the expression for $x_i$.

I tried to approximate the solution by setting $x_i=f(i)$ to get $$f(i+1)-f(i)=a\cdot f(i)^{\frac{2-2\alpha}{3}},$$ and then treating the difference like a derivative so that $$f'(i)=a\cdot f(i)^{\frac{2-2\alpha}{3}}.$$ Solving this gives me $x_i=(a\cdot i+C)^\frac{3}{2\alpha+1}$ where $C$ is a constant dependent on initial conditions. I think this would be good enough if I could show that the true value of $x_i$ is never lower than what I derived. I see from the original equation how for $\alpha=1$ my result is exact.

I see now that for $\alpha>1$, my approximation is too low which for my purpose is acceptable. I still have to take care of the case when $\alpha <1$.

Comment: $x_i$ strictly increasing, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: If $x_i$ strictly increasing then it's lower bound is ...?

Comment: I might have worded this wrong. I'm not looking for a lower bound on the set of all $x_i$ but for an approximation of $x_i$ that is equal to or less than the true $x_i$ for every $i$.

Comment: I suppose there are infinitely many such functions (they called *minorant*)

Comment: I know I could just take $x_i=k$ where $k<0$ and it would meet my requirements but I also want to be at least somewhat close to the true values.

Comment: I think, you may reformulate question like "how to find asymptotics", "O-big" or smth like that. It's more informative

Comment: Will do, I have to be more careful.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, whatever $\alpha$ might be, if $x_0 > 0$ the sequence is increasing.

As a first approximation, if you disregard the troublesome term you have $x_n$ constant. Plug this into the recurrence:

$$
x_{n + 1} - x_n = x_0^{\frac{2 - 2 \alpha}{3}}
$$

which gives:

$$
x_n = x_0 + n \cdot x_0^{\frac{2 - 2 \alpha}{3}}
$$

We are underestimating $x_n$ here, so this is a lower bound. If not accurate enough, rinse and repeat. It gets ugly, perhaps estimating the sum by an integral is enough.